# Search for Specific text in a File and Copy the Following Content in JAVA

Tags: java, file, bufferedreader

I am reading a file using BufferedReader and finding a text in the file. If the text is found, the following content need to be copied into another file.
The content of the file looks like following:

```
...............
Transforming com.depositmobi.ActivationDoneActivity... 
Transforming com.depositmobi.ReadOffertActivity... 
Transforming dummyMainClass... 
Inside Possible Callers !
cg.size(): 976
sources: false null
Finished !!!!
CLINIT edge: $r1 = new com.depositmobi.Main in <dummyMainClass: void dummyMainMethod(java.lang.String[])> ==> <com.depositmobi.Main: void <clinit>()>
STATIC edge: staticinvoke <com.depositmobi.Main: void <clinit>()>() in <dummyMainClass: void dummyMainMethod(java.lang.String[])> ==> <com.depositmobi.Main: void <clinit>()>
CLINIT edge: $r12 = new android.view.View in <dummyMainClass: void dummyMainMethod(java.lang.String[])> ==> <android.view.View: void <clinit>()>
CLINIT edge: $r11 = new android.os.Bundle in <dummyMainClass: void dummyMainMethod(java.lang.String[])> ==> <android.os.Bundle: void <clinit>()>
CLINIT edge: $r10 = new com.depositmobi.ReadOffertActivity in <dummyMainClass: void dummyMainMethod(java.lang.String[])> ==> <android.app.Activity: void <clinit>()>
 ................
```

If the word *'Finished !!!!'* is found in the text file, copy the entire contents, afterwards into a file named *soot.txt*.

Using the following code, I am able to read contents before 'finished !!!'. How to get the content after finished?

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
while (!br.readLine().startsWith("Finished !!!!")) {
            System.out.println(br.readLine() );
    }
```

Comment: Is `Finished !!!!` occurring only once in the file?

Comment: What have you already tried ? If you haven't tried anything yet, please do start and then ask a question when you are stuck. Please provide some code. Please also take a moment to read [how-to-ask on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: yes. I've added it manually to identify the split position.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code.

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file)); 
String line;
Boolean finishedFound = Boolean.FALSE;
StringBuilder contents = new StringBuilder();
while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            if(line.startsWith("Finished !!!!")) {
                finishedFound = Boolean.TRUE;
                continue;
            }
            if(finishedFound) {
                contents.append(line+System.lineSeparator());
            }

        }
 // Here your code to write the contents to soot.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```
List<String> linesAfterFinish = new ArrayList<>();
try(BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file))){
    boolean conditionWasMeet = false;
    for(String line; (line = br.readLine()) != null){
        if(conditionWasMeet){
            linesAfterFinish.add(line);
        }
        if(!conditionWasMeet && line.startsWith("Finished !!!!")){
            conditionWasMeet = true;
        }
    }
}catch(Exception e){
    e.printStackTrace();
}


if(!linesAfterFinish.isEmpty()){
    /// Write the content of linesAfterFinish to the other file.
}
```